# PHP Not sent automatic email on remote server

Tags: php

I wrote codes that should send auto email using PEAR. every thing is OK on my local MAC OS system but not working on windows based remote server. here is my codes:

```
<?php require_once('../config/connection.php'); 
include_once("Mail.php"); 
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['update-visa-status-btn'])){
    $status=$_POST['status'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `visa` SET `status`='$status' WHERE `id`='$id'");
$visa=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `visa` WHERE `id`='$id'");
$row_visa=mysqli_fetch_assoc($visa);
$user_id=$row_visa['userid'];
$user_info=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id`='$user_id'");
$row_user_info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_info);
$From = "..."; 
$To="...";
$Subject = "..."; 
$Message = '
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- SOME HTML CODES THAT MAKES HTML EMAIL BODY -->
</body>
</html>'; 
$Host = "..."; 
$Username = "..."; 
$Password = "..."; 
$content_type="text/html"; 
$Headers = array ('From' => $From, 'To' => $To, 'Subject' => $Subject, 'content-type' => $content_type); 
$SMTP = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $Host, 'auth' => true, 
'username' => $Username, 'password' => $Password)); 
$mail = $SMTP->send($To, $Headers, $Message); 
if (PEAR::isError($mail)){ 
echo($mail->getMessage()); 
} else { 
echo("Email Message sent!"); 
}}
?>
```

On remote server none of messages success or error not shown & no email sent but on local, every thing works like a charm.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just by the way, someone could wreck your database by sending any `status` and `id` `' OR '1'='1`.

Answer (score 0):

First please escape the GET and POST variables:

`$escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string)`

Secondly: For Email sending purpose use PHPMailer a free repository to send emails. You can get this from github: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer There you will also find the Process you need to follow to get your emails sent.

I'm using this PHPMailer for ages now. It is easy, robust and hardly fails on me.